# how to get dropdown value onchange in jquery wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

**my view page on change alert i am not getting**

```
<table width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="form-field form-required">
                    <th scope="row"><label for="Country">Country</label></th>
                    <td><select name="country_id" id="country_id" onchange="country_change();" class="form-control" aria-required="true" ><option value="" >Select</option>
                    <?php foreach ($country_list as $obj) { 
                    echo "<option value=".$obj->id.">".$obj->country."</option>";  } ?></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="form-field form-required">
                    <th scope="row"><label for="state">State</label></th>
                    <td><select name="state_id" id="state_id" class="form-control" aria-required="true" ><option value="" >Select</option>
                    <?php //foreach ($country_list as $obj) { 
                    //echo "<option value=".$obj->id.">".$obj->country."</option>";  } ?></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="form-field form-required">
                    <th scope="row"><label for="city">City</label></th>
                    <td><input name="city" type="text" id="city" value="" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" maxlength="60"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**my script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function country_change() {
        alert('abdul');
            var country_id = $('#country_id').val();
            alert(country_id);

    }
</script>
```

**i am new in **WordPress**.  i am getting one alert only .second alert i am not getting**

Comment: When you click again you click an other value ? because the function country_change() not call if you click on the selected value in your select.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onchange

Comment: thnq now its working

Comment: You can do it with AJAX in your case, use admin-ajax.php. This could be useful https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/